# Can GPU communicate with Southbridge independently?

Tags: cuda, hardware, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

In a CUDA code, you can access host side memory by zero-copying. Based on below picture from Wikipedia, the access request goes through Northbridge and is fulfilled without interrupting CPU.

1. Is it possible for GPU (at least in theory) to access Southbridge components like I/O independent of CPU? As far as I know in practice, during CUDA coding it's not possible (yet).
2. Based on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_800_Series) Wikipedia link, 2014 generation of CUDA devices named Maxwell will have an ARM CPU inside. If the answer to above question is yes, how much this ARM CPU can control or communicate I/O?

[image]

Comment: I'd imagine it depends in no small part on whether I/O ports and/or MMIO ranges can be entirely independent of the CPU.  If they can, and if CUDA doesn't restrict what addresses you can access, you might have a shot.  (I don't know CUDA, though, so this is all just spitballing.)

Comment: The short answer to the first question is no.  For the second question, NVIDIA has not publicly announced details of the Maxwell architecture, so if you're asking for non-public information, that is not an appropriate SO question.  Furthermore since the answer to the first question is no (see my comment on Roger's answer), and you predicate your second question on "if the answer to above question is yes...", it would seem that your second question is moot.

Comment: The answer that Nvidia hasn't included this feature (so far) is clear. My question is how is it not possible even in theory? Do all communications to Southbridge have to be initiated only by CPU? Besides, when GPU can access host RAM directly without interrupting CPU, why can't we make GPU communicate with an IO (e.g. mouse) by having a memory-mapped IO? (I'm sorry my question here might be naive.)

Answer (score 2):

Check [GPUDirect](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect). [Technical](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/gpudirect-rdma/index.html).

> RDMA for GPUDirect is a feature introduced in Kepler-class GPUs and CUDA 5.0 that enables a direct path for communication between the GPU and a peer device using standard features of PCI Express. The devices must share the same upstream root complex. A few straightforward changes must be made to device drivers to enable this functionality with a wide range of hardware devices. This document introduces the technology and describes the steps necessary to enable an RDMA for GPUDirect connection to NVIDIA GPUs on Linux.

Comment: GPUDirect RDMA transfers are triggered entirely from host code, not device code.  The CUDA device has no direct way to trigger a transfer to another device.  The exception is Peer-to-Peer, and that only works between 2 GPUs (on the same root complex).  There is no way in current CUDA architecture to access another device, if it is not another CUDA GPU, from CUDA code.

Comment: I didn't interpret the question as requiring that the transfers be triggered from device code. Maybe that's what the OP is after, but triggering RDMA transfers to non-GPU devices from a kernel doesn't seem like it would make sense.

Comment: The OP says "independent of the CPU".  Since the CPU is required to trigger a transfer, I don't see how that could be viewed as "independent of the CPU".  That was the reason for my comment.  Zero-copy, referenced in the question (and peer-to-peer) fit the description of "independent" or "without interrupting the CPU" as they require no triggering to initiate the transfer.

Comment: Thanks Roger. But your answer doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, would you add an answer? Then I'll go ahead and delete this one.

Comment: Since I am permitted to vote on your answer according to my own opinion, and since the tooltip help associated with the upvote button says "This answer is useful" I have upvoted your answer.  I find it to be useful.  My comments merely were intended to add additional information to your useful answer.  GPUDirect *is* a possible approach to enabling multi-device direct communication, which is at least tangentially related to the question.  Again, that's my opinion.  I don't see any need to provide my own answer.  I find yours to have already captured anything I might have to say.  My opinion.